# MySQL : Select records with conditions that applies to multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql, select, row

I have a table:

**DETAILS**

```
--------------------------------------------------------
ID    |   PARENT_ID    |    DATA_KEY     |   DATA_VALUE
======================================================== 
1     |      1         |     Guitar      |      4
--------------------------------------------------------
2     |      1         |     Radio       |      2
--------------------------------------------------------
3     |      1         |     Tv          |      2
--------------------------------------------------------
4     |      1         |     Drum Kit    |      3
--------------------------------------------------------
5     |      2         |     Guitar      |      4
--------------------------------------------------------
6     |      2         |     Radio       |      2
--------------------------------------------------------
7     |      2         |     Tv          |      2
--------------------------------------------------------
8     |      2         |     Drum Kit    |      3
--------------------------------------------------------
9     |      3         |     Guitar      |      1
--------------------------------------------------------
10    |      3         |     Radio       |      2
--------------------------------------------------------
11    |      3         |     Tv          |      2
--------------------------------------------------------
12    |      3         |     Drum Kit    |      3
--------------------------------------------------------
```

How do i select in mysql distinct PARENT_ID that satisfies the below conditions:

- 1. DATA_KEY = 'Guitar' and DATA_VALUE = '4'
- 1. DATA_KEY = 'Radio' and
     DATA_VALUE = '2'

Expected output of the query should be

```
-------------
PARENT_ID
=============
  1
-------------
  2
-------------
```

Since only PARENT_ID 1 and 2 has 'Guitar' = '4' and 'Radio' = '2'

Comment: I have tried SELECT DISTINCT PARENT_ID FROM DETAILS WHERE (DATA_KEY = 'Guitar' AND DATA_VALUE = '4') AND (DATA_KEY = 'Radio' AND DATA_VALUE = '2') but it returns me empty data

Comment: use OR instead of AND (the one out of the brackets)

Comment: I've answered with a query that will get what you're looking for.  I don't, however, understand WHY this is useful to you.  Frankly, the entire data setup looks questionable to me - I'm guessing more knowledge of the table schema is required to understand the use.

Comment: Dude, your answer is wrong.  it will return PARENT_ID 1,2 and 3.

Comment: I wont ask for something it it's not useful to me or to somebody out there that might be in the same trouble.  anyway thanks for your wrong answer.

Comment: @Macchiato His answer is correct because there is a row where parent_id = 3, data_key = Radio and data_value = 2. Using the data you provided that is an expected result unless you specifically exclude parent_id  = 3 from the results. If you are looking for results where the parent_id is one that has both of those conditions then that is something you need to clarify in your question.

Comment: @JoeW: He is apparantly looking for something which satisfies BOTH criteria, not just one.  Knowing that, he absolutely needs to join the table to itself.

Comment: @JoeW It is very clear in the description,  How do i select in mysql distinct PARENT_ID that satisfies the below conditions:

        DATA_KEY = 'Guitar' and DATA_VALUE = '4'
        DATA_KEY = 'Radio' and DATA_VALUE = '2'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.parent_id 
FROM details AS a
JOIN details AS b ON a.parent_id=b.parent_id
WHERE a.data_key='Guitar' AND a.data_value='4' AND
      b.data_key='Radio' AND b.data_value='2';
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this query will also return empty rows because the conditions "a.data_key='Guitar' AND a.data_value='4' AND
      b.data_key='Radio' AND a.data_value='2'" is actually executed on a single row which will always return false because a single row can not have a.data_key = 'Guitar' and a.data_key = 'Radio'

Comment: I think you just typed wrongly, i changed a.data_value='2' to b.data_value='2' and it returns the correct result. thanks!

Comment: @Macchiato Yes.  It was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Parent_Id
FROM details
WHERE (data_key='Guitar' AND data_value='4') OR
(data_key='Radio' AND data_value='2')
```

That will get the results you requested.

What you commented as having tried was close, but it was using an 'AND' instead of an 'OR'.

Comment: This is wrong, you used OR which will return PARENT_ID 1,2 and 3.  The condition is to satisfy data_key = 'Guitar' and data_value'4' AND data_key'Radio' and data_value='2'

Comment: @Macchiato: But your 2nd criteria is "data_key='Radio' and data_value='2'".  In your sample set, this ALSO matches row 10.

Never mind, I see where my problem was.  You are looking for a parentId which satisfies both criteria, not parentIds which satisfy either criteria.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you look for this

```
   SELECT  a.parent_id 
  FROM details AS a
  JOIN details AS b ON a.parent_id=b.parent_id
  WHERE a.data_key='Guitar' AND a.data_value='4' AND
     b.data_key='Radio' AND b.data_value='2'
  group by a.parent_id ;
```

[demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ba282/4)