# how to select multiple key value from one table with one query?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

this is sample product properties table

```
product_id  property_id property_value
5           1           white
5           2           50
5           3           50
5           4           55
5           5           mm
6           8           cm
```

i want filter my products dynamically. for example:

```
select property_id 1 and property_value white
AND
select property_id 2 and property_value 50
AND
select property_id 4 and property_value 55
AND
etc ...
```

i can make dynamic query from a basic query. when i use all conditions together, no record matched because all conditions operator is AND. what is the best query?
thanks for your answers.

Comment: How could one row match all those criteria?

Comment: no one row, i want all row matched with separated conditions. (property_id property_value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Heading ##The basic query is:

```
SELECT
  a.`*`,b.`*`
FROM
  properties AS a
JOIN
  properties AS b
ON
  a.`product_id` = b.`product_id`
WHERE
    a.`property_id` = '1' AND a.`property_value` = 'white' 
    AND 
    b.`property_id` = '2' AND b.`property_value` = '50'
```

Thanks to @mikhail-vladimirov https://stackoverflow.com/a/15208055/5129662

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're using the wrong keyword. Use `OR` instead of `AND` between the sets of criteria:

```
SELECT DISTINCT product_id

FROM product_properties

WHERE
(property_id = 1 and property_value = 'white')
OR
(property_id = 2 and property_value = '50')
OR
(property_id = 4 and property_value = '55')
OR
etc ...
```

You can use `DISTINCT` if you just want one of each `product_id` that matches the various criteria, or leave it off to get one for each row that matches.

Comment: because i want all products with these properties.

Comment: Probably needs `property_id=1 and property_value='white'` and so on.

Comment: @tadman Thanks, yeah. I just copy/pasted and I keep seeing more and more stuff I overlooked changing