# MySQL : Timeout when selecting records with conditions that applies to multiple rows

Tags: mysql

In a large database, I get a timeout as soon as I combine multiple left joins to find objects that have multiple rows with matching conditions.

I want to find all objects that have in a different table the property "Red", "Monster Engine", "Blinker" and "Roaring" set.

So I have a MYSQL table with contact Objects called "objects":

```
| id |deleted|
===============
| 1  | false |
| 2  | false |  
| 3  | false |
```

Each object has properties stored in another table "properties_relations"

```
|  id  |  objectId  |  propertyId  |  valueString     |
=======================================================
| 12   |   1        |   43         |    Red           |
| 13   |   1        |   44         |    Monster Engine|
| 14   |   1        |   45         |    Blinker       |
| 15   |   1        |   46         |    Roaring       |
```

Now I want to select all Objects that have a property with the value "Red" and the value "Monster Engine".

I did it this way according to this post [MySQL : Select records with conditions that applies to multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15208004/mysql-select-records-with-conditions-that-applies-to-multiple-rows):

```
select * from `objects` 
    left join `properties_relations` as `properties_relations` on `objects`.`id` = `properties_relations`.`objectId` 
    left join `properties_relations` as `properties_relations_b` on `objects`.`id` = `properties_relations`.`objectId` 
        
    where (`properties_relations`.`propertyId` = 43 and (`properties_relations`.`valueString` = "Red") 
            and `properties_relations_b`.`propertyId` = 44 and (`properties_relations_b`.`valueString` = "Monster Engine") 
          ) 
           and `objects`.`deleted` = 0
```

This his, however, working. But as soon as I add a third or fourth condition I will get in a timeout. I saw that the number of rows is increasing exponentially the more joins I add.

The query that is NOT working looks like this:

```sql
    select * from `objects` 
    left join `properties_relations` as `properties_relations` on `objects`.`id` = `properties_relations`.`objectId` 
    left join `properties_relations` as `properties_relations_b` on `objects`.`id` = `properties_relations`.`objectId` 

    left join `properties_relations` as `properties_relations_c` on `objects`.`id` = `properties_relations`.`objectId` 

    left join `properties_relations` as `properties_relations_d` on `objects`.`id` = `properties_relations`.`objectId` 
        
    where (`properties_relations`.`propertyId` = 43 and 
 (`properties_relations`.`valueString` = "Red") 
            and `properties_relations_b`.`propertyId` = 44 and (`properties_relations_b`.`valueString` = "Monster Engine") 

  and `properties_relations_c`.`propertyId` = 45 and (`properties_relations_c`.`valueString` = "Blinker") 

  and `properties_relations_d`.`propertyId` = 46 and (`properties_relations_d`.`valueString` = "Roaring") 
          ) 
           and `objects`.`deleted` = 0
```

So what can I do about this?

Comment: include the query that *didn't* work.   This question would be a lot easier to answer if you created a db fiddle  on a site such as https://dbfiddle.uk/ (no affiliation, I just think they do a good job)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the join being used for the relation of the between `objects` and `properties_relations` is using the wrong name.

You are using **alias** for the `properties_relations` tables, while the **actual table name** is the one being used on the join condition.

This is the query that I have modified:

```
select
    *
from
    `objects`
    left join `properties_relations` as `properties_relations` on `objects`.`id` = `properties_relations`.`objectId`
        and `properties_relations`.`propertyId` = 43
    left join `properties_relations` as `properties_relations_b` on `objects`.`id` = `properties_relations_b`.`objectId`
        and `properties_relations_b`.`propertyId` = 44
    left join `properties_relations` as `properties_relations_c` on `objects`.`id` = `properties_relations_c`.`objectId`
        and `properties_relations_c`.`propertyId` = 45
    left join `properties_relations` as `properties_relations_d` on `objects`.`id` = `properties_relations_d`.`objectId`
        and `properties_relations_d`.`propertyId` = 46
where
    (
        and (`properties_relations`.`valueString` = "Red")
        and (`properties_relations_b`.`valueString` = "Monster Engine")
        and (`properties_relations_c`.`valueString` = "Blinker")
        and (`properties_relations_d`.`valueString` = "Roaring")
    )
    and `objects`.`deleted` = 0
```

In the above query, I have also moved the `propertyId` field from where condition to join condition. This is in order to reduce the rows being returned so that the query can be run faster.

Comment: This did the trick - the "and" condition in the join prevented that many rows were returned. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You are using AND Operand instead of OR. Since all those valueStrings are not on the same row. till eternity, it will return NULL because all those are not on the same row.

Comment: SELECT * FROM `properties_relations` t1
LEFT JOIN objects t2 ON t2.id = t1.objectid
WHERE (t1.propertyid = 43 and t1.valuestring = "Red")
OR (t1.propertyid = 44 and t1.valuestring = "Monster Engine")
OR (t1.propertyid = 45 and t1.valuestring = "Blinker")
OR (t1.propertyid = 46 and t1.valuestring = "Roaring")
AND t2.deleted = 'false'

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM objects
  LEFT JOIN properties_relations AS properties_relations
    ON objects.id = properties_relations.objectId
  WHERE properties_relations.valueString
    IN ("Red","Monster Engine") AND objects.deleted = 0;
```

Comment: Nope, thats not working because Red, Monster Engine etc. are not on the same row